# How to convert SCSS to CSS with auto vendor prefixer?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

Is there any way of converting SCSS to CSS with automatic vendor prefixes? I have used **node-sass** with npm and it worked perfectly, but it is not rendering vendor prefixes automatically (like `box-sizing: border-box;` or `display: flex;` properties)

**Note:** I have used the sass compiler extension VS Code, but it is rendering the CSS and CSS.MAP files in the same directory of the SCSS files which I do not want.

Comment: You can use https://postcss.org/ autoprefixer and node-sass in webpack which allows you to config where you want to output your files

Comment: It works perfectly.. I am using `gulp-postcss` and `gulp-sourcemaps`.

`gulp.task('css', () => {
  const postcss    = require('gulp-postcss')
  const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')

  return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
    .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
    .pipe( postcss([ require('precss'), require('autoprefixer') ]) )
    .pipe( sourcemaps.write('.') )
    .pipe( gulp.dest('build/') )
})`

Comment: If that is the answer than you can answer your own question. That will help other users as well

Comment: Oh yeah sure! I am newbie so, thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this
https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: It works , but you have to do the extra steps of first converting your SCSS to CSS and then putting your code in the online converter. The [postcss.org](https://postcss.org/) works just fine with my workflow.

Comment: there is a lot of npm packages for autoprefix you can try one

Answer (score 0):

I found [postcss](https://postcss.org/) works perfectly. I am doing this:

**Gulp**

Use `gulp-postcss` and `gulp-sourcemaps`.

```
gulp.task('css', () => {
  const postcss    = require('gulp-postcss')
  const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')

  return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
    .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
    .pipe( postcss([ require('precss'), require('autoprefixer') ]) )
    .pipe( sourcemaps.write('.') )
    .pipe( gulp.dest('build/') )
})
```

Please refer this page: [usage](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#gulp)